# Bing Webmaster Tools missing www

Tags: no-www, bing-webmaster-tools

I've been using the Index Explorer and Crawl Information in Bing Webmaster Tools to identify 301 redirects & 404 errors. I've noticed however that all of the links are listed without the `www.` before the root domain, even though the domain was added with the `www.` and shows as `www.domain.com` in the Dashboard. I'm also already redirecting `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` and have canonical links in place.

Google Webmaster Tools has an option to set "Preferred domain" as either including the `www.` or not, but I can't find anything like this in Bing's version. Is there an option for this? Is there another way to stop Bing from reporting on URL's without the `www.`?